# Clearer comparison of modified titles

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

When the title of a question is edited, the suggested edits page shows something like this:
[image: Modified title]
That's incredibly hard to parse. It would be much nicer to see something like this:
[image: tkdiff comparison]
which is what tkdiff, a program from c. 1994, shows.

Comment: Assuming we don't actually use that color scheme I'm on board

Comment: @Michael: It's a deal.